# Where does boundedness feature in this argument?

Tags: measure-theory

An assignment question asks:

> Let $\nu$ be a finite signed measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.  Show that $$\left|\int_X f d\nu\right| \leq \int_X|f|d|\nu|$$

My solution is simply:

$$\left|\int_X f d\nu\right| = \left|\int_X f d(\nu^+-\nu^-)\right| = \left|\int_X f d\nu^+-\int_X f d\nu^-\right| \leq \left|\int_X f d\nu^+\right|+\left|\int_X f d\nu^-\right|$$

$$\leq \int_X |f| d\nu^++\int_X |f| d\nu^-= \int_X |f| d(\nu^++\nu^-) = \int_X|f| d|\nu|$$

But this seems too easy. We didn't use boundedness at all.

> **Question.** Where does boundedness feature in this argument?

Comment: Do you need boundededness to guarantee that your third expression is well-defined (i.e., not $| \infty - \infty |$)?

Comment: @David, yep, I reckon that's it. Thanks :)